# How is the OpenCV PCA mean calculated

Tags: opencv, pca

I'm using OpenCV to calculate the PCA for a set of pixels represented as 2D points. But I'm unsure how PCA is calculating the mean of these points, as it is not what I would expect.

If I have the following 3 points `(x,y)`:

```
(2,1), (2,2), (2,3)
```

And I then calculate the PCA (OpenCvSharp is used, but it is just a wrapper):

```
Mat input = new Mat(3,2, MatType.CV_32FC1);
input.Set(0,0, 2f);
input.Set(0,1, 1f);
input.Set(1,0, 2f);
input.Set(1,1, 2f);
input.Set(2,0, 2f);
input.Set(2,1, 3f);

Mat mean = new Mat();
PCA pcaResult = new PCA(input, mean, PCA.Flags.DataAsRow);

float meanX = pcaResult.Mean.Get<float>(0,0);
float meanY = pcaResult.Mean.Get<float>(0,1);
```

`meanX` and `meanY` are `(0.6666667, 0)`, respectively. Where as I would have expected them to be `(2,2)` (I'm guessing some form of normalisation is occurring). How is the PCA mean being calculated, and what do I need to do to calculate the mean that I expect? Or do I need to pass the mean into `PCA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this porting in C++ of your code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat1f input = (Mat1f(3,2) << 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3);

    PCA pca(input, Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW);

    float meanX = pca.mean.at<float>(0, 0);
    float meanY = pca.mean.at<float>(0, 1);

    std::cout << meanX << " - " << meanY << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

I got the mean as `(2,2)`, as expected. Probably is an issue with C# wrapper.

---

The mean is ultimately computed by the method `calcCovarMatrix` as a reduction operation:

```
...
bool takeRows = (flags & CV_COVAR_ROWS) != 0;
ctype = std::max(CV_MAT_DEPTH(ctype >= 0 ? ctype : type), CV_32F);
...
reduce( _src, _mean, takeRows ? 0 : 1, CV_REDUCE_AVG, ctype );
```

Comment: Yeah, it turns out it was OpenCvSharp, the Mean returns the Eigenvalues. I have posted the issue on OpenCvSharp's Github page.